# FreeBSD: What is the counterpart to apt called?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, freebsd

I'm about to install FreeBSD 12.1. I'm a longtime Ubuntu user, and I prefer to install apps via the command line. Just wondering.

Answer (score 6):

The FreeBSD project has a very good [Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/) covering most aspects of using the system.

For example, there is a chapter dedicated to [Installing Applications: Packages and Ports](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports.html).

In it, you will get to know that the command that is used for installation of pre-compiled 3rd party software is called [`pkg`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&sektion=8&manpath=freebsd-release-ports):

> A FreeBSD package contains pre-compiled copies of all the commands for an application, as well as any configuration files and documentation. A package can be manipulated with the `pkg(8)` commands, such as `pkg install`.

Comment: Thank you Gilles and Kusalanada. These were more than satisfactory answers.